# Constructing a Nat type

Tags: haskell, types

I'm currently learning about using Nat from GHC.TypeLits

I am trying to lift an integer to the type level for testing via these definitions:

```
type IntNat (t::Nat) = Int

incNat :: IntNat t -> IntNat (t + 1)
incNat n = n + 1

fromInt :: Int -> IntNat t
fromInt(0) = (0 :: IntNat 0)
fromInt(n) = incNat (fromInt(n-1))

four = fromInt 4
```

From my understanding this should result in:

```
four = 4 :: IntNat (Nat 4)
```

However I am getting:

```
four = 4 :: IntNat t
```

Where am I going wrong, is it just that `fromInt` is erasing the type information?

Comment: I doubt that `fromInt` compiles. Could you produce an MCVE to show your problem?

Comment: According to your definition `IntNat t = Int` for all `t`. Your signatures are exactly equivalent to `incNat :: Int->Int` and `fromInt :: Int->Int`. `four` has types `IntNat (Nat 0), IntNat (Nat 1), ...`, all of them actually being `Int`. For some reason, the type inference engine prefer the form `IntNat t`, as if it were the most general type (it is, but so are all the others). Note that, crucially, you are using a type synonym and not a `newtype`.

Comment: It is quite clear that `fromInt :: Int -> IntNat t` so any time you apply it to a value of type Int you will get a value of type `IntNat t`.  You seem to be wanting dependent types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you defined a type synonym, and not a newtype, the meaning is quite different than what you seem to think.  Roughly, `IntNat _` will unify with `Int` and thus any other `IntNat _`.

You can try this out by defining other intnats and see them unify in, say, a list:

```
*Main> let five = 5 :: IntNat 99
*Main> let xs = [four, five] :: [IntNat 42]
*Main> :t xs
xs :: [IntNat 42]
```

or using a single intnat:

```
*Main> let four' = four :: IntNat 1000
*Main> :t four'
four' :: IntNat 1000
```

Instead consider using a newtype, such as `newtype IntNat (n :: Nat) = IN Int`.  You'd get an error like:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘t’ with ‘0’
  ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      fromInt :: forall (t :: Nat). Int -> IntNat t
    at so.hs:12:1-26
  Expected type: IntNat t
    Actual type: IntNat 0
• In the expression: IN 0 :: IntNat 0
  In an equation for ‘fromInt’: fromInt 0 = IN 0 :: IntNat 0
• Relevant bindings include
    fromInt :: Int -> IntNat t (bound at so.hs:13:1)
```

This is because `t` and `0` are not the same - `t` is universal not existential.  The offending lines are:

```
fromInt :: Int -> IntNat t
fromInt 0 = 0 :: IntNat 0
```

`forall t. t == 0` is a hard proof to write